# Joomla 1.5 : How to find number of concurrent / active users in my joomla based intranet system

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

I have a Joomla 1.5.10 based Intranet system. Sometimes we see that number of DB threads are too high and performance become down. When I checked through Administrator section, I can see the number of logged-in users only. These number is between 1000-5000 only. is it correct to execute below query to find the concurrent active users:

```
select count(*) from jos_session;
```

For example, If I execute above query and check the logged-in user through administrator, below is the data:

```
select count(*) from jos_session; = 2628
logged-in users visible from admin section = 1545
```

Both results are not matching each other. Also, what is the best way to find the concurrent / active users in my system at a time?

Comment: Please upgrade to 1.5.26 + apply latest patches, 1.5.10 is highly insecure

Answer (score 1):

**I think just by analizing `__session` you won't get the info you need / want.** If you need to understand what you see in back-end, check the module located at:

`administrator\modules\mod_status\mod_status.php`

There are all the queries listed. Important is to understand that `guest` is an user which is not authenticated, and also client_id (front-end (0) VS backend authentication (1)).

Here is the thing:

- `jos_session` stores all the sessions that have not expired
- probably you have a SSO authentication mechanism, which means that the user probably get a new session id if it closes and opens again the browser. Having more `active` sessions than users it's a clear sign that the session expiration time is set to high.

Just do a query against the `jos_session`:

```
SELECT `username`, count(username) FROM `jos_session` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `username`
```

If too many users have a too large value for `count`, reduce the session lifetime.

This way you will get a more realistic figure on how many users are at a certain time in the system, but again this is just a session, it does not provide you with exact information on how many users are actually performing an action on a website.

To put it in plain English is like saying: I know that 1500 users opened the Intranet in the last [FILL IN SESSION LIFETIME] minutes.

[image: Session settings]

You need to understand how exactly do the DB threads get generated and why the value is high.

Basically, quoting the [documentation](http://us.php.net/function.mysql-connect), `The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close().`

Might be worth checking if you have something like a JavaScript polling your server with AJAX requests to get some info, which might run even if the user just has the browser open.

Hope this helps in a way or another.

Comment: Many Thanks Valentin for clarification. In my system, there is no provision for guest user. Only after login, a user can enter into the application. Also, when I execute the query give by you, I found that there are only few users for which count >=4. Maximum users have 1-2 count only. Even, execution of this script, there is a difference between logged-in users displayed in admin section (1966) and number of records fetched after execution of the above query (1579). How can I manage the session lifetime in my application?

Comment: In Jooma -> Global Configuration -> System -> Session Settings (should be something similar in 1.5.)

Comment: Thanks, I got the settings and found that session lifetime is 120 minutes.